# Doctrine Migration error Integrity constraint violation 1052 Column 'TABLE_NAME' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, symfony, mariadb, doctrine, migration

When I launch for the first time (on php container) :

```bash
$ php bin/console d:m:m -n --allow-no-migration
```

It's work fine but when I launch for second time the same command I have the error :

```
 In ExceptionConverter.php line 72:
                                                                                                                               
  An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'TABLE_NAME' in  
   where clause is ambiguous                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                               
In Exception.php line 28:
                                                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'TABLE_NAME' in where clause is ambiguous  
                                                                                                          
In Statement.php line 130:
                                                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'TABLE_NAME' in where clause is ambiguous
```

When I reproduce whith Xampp3.3.0 :

- .env => DATABASE_URL='mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/webapp3?serverVersion=mariadb-10.9.3'
  It's work fine.

For both configuration, information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_NAME exists.
I checked my doctrine migration configuration with https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/3.3.x/UPGRADE.md
On my Xampp I have: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.24-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision b4477ae73c836592268f7fb231eeb38a4fa83bb6
On Docker : mysql  Ver 8.2.0 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

The SQL statement :

```sql
SELECT  c.COLUMN_NAME AS field, 
IF(  c.COLUMN_TYPE = 'longtext'  AND EXISTS( SELECT * from information_schema.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'symfony'  AND TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME AND CHECK_CLAUSE = CONCAT( 'json_valid(`',  c.COLUMN_NAME,  '`)'  )  ), 
   'json', c.COLUMN_TYPE  )  AS type, c.IS_NULLABLE  AS `null`,   c.COLUMN_KEY  AS `key`, c.COLUMN_DEFAULT AS `default`,  c.EXTRA,  c.COLUMN_COMMENT AS comment,  c.CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS characterset, c.COLLATION_NAME AS collation 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c     INNER JOIN information_schema.TABLES t   ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME     
WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? 
AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
AND t.TABLE_NAME = ? 
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

My composer.json :

```json
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.10",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.17"
```

Someone could help me please ?

Here my project to test: https://gitlab.com/simon-toullec/webapp3

Logs :

```
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.048906+01:00] deprecation.INFO: User Deprecated: Version detection logic for MySQL will change in DBAL 4. Please specify the version as the server reports it, e.g. "10.9.3-MariaDB" instead of "mariadb-10.9". (AbstractMySQLDriver.php:149 called by AbstractMySQLDriver.php:42, https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/5779, package doctrine/orm) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Version detection logic for MySQL will change in DBAL 4. Please specify the version as the server reports it, e.g. \"10.9.3-MariaDB\" instead of \"mariadb-10.9\". (AbstractMySQLDriver.php:149 called by AbstractMySQLDriver.php:42, https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/5779, package doctrine/orm) at D:\\workspace\\PHP\\SYMFONY\\webapp3\\vendor\\doctrine\\deprecations\\lib\\Doctrine\\Deprecations\\Deprecation.php:210)"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.054779+01:00] doctrine.INFO: Connecting with parameters array{"driver":"pdo_mysql","host":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"user":"root","password":null,"driverOptions":[],"defaultTableOptions":{"collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},"dbname":"webapp3","serverVersion":"mariadb-10.9.3","charset":"utf8mb4"} {"params":{"driver":"pdo_mysql","host":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"user":"root","password":null,"driverOptions":[],"defaultTableOptions":{"collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},"dbname":"webapp3","serverVersion":"mariadb-10.9.3","charset":"utf8mb4"}} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.062498+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.204907+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.240184+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?   AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME (parameters: array{"1":"webapp3"}, types: array{"1":2}) {"sql":"SELECT TABLE_NAME\nFROM information_schema.TABLES\nWHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?\n  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'\nORDER BY TABLE_NAME","params":{"1":"webapp3"},"types":{"1":2}} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.437204+01:00] deprecation.INFO: User Deprecated: Subscribing to onSchemaCreateTable events is deprecated. (AbstractPlatform.php:2179 called by AbstractPlatform.php:2077, https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/5784, package doctrine/dbal) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Subscribing to onSchemaCreateTable events is deprecated. (AbstractPlatform.php:2179 called by AbstractPlatform.php:2077, https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/5784, package doctrine/dbal) at D:\\workspace\\PHP\\SYMFONY\\webapp3\\vendor\\doctrine\\deprecations\\lib\\Doctrine\\Deprecations\\Deprecation.php:210)"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.614339+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: CREATE TABLE doctrine_migration_versions (version VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL, executed_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, execution_time INT DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(version)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB {"sql":"CREATE TABLE doctrine_migration_versions (version VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL, executed_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, execution_time INT DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(version)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.721506+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions {"sql":"SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.738872+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions {"sql":"SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.739850+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions {"sql":"SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.800811+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Beginning transaction [] []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.864878+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: CREATE TABLE director (id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, person_type_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, gender_type_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, birth_date DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_1E90D3F0E7D23F1A (person_type_id), INDEX IDX_1E90D3F037A4F92F (gender_type_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB {"sql":"CREATE TABLE director (id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, person_type_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, gender_type_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, birth_date DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_1E90D3F0E7D23F1A (person_type_id), INDEX IDX_1E90D3F037A4F92F (gender_type_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.884331+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: CREATE TABLE gender_type (id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB {"sql":"CREATE TABLE gender_type (id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.894582+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: CREATE TABLE person_type (id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB {"sql":"CREATE TABLE person_type (id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.904303+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: CREATE TABLE `user` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)', password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB {"sql":"CREATE TABLE `user` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)', password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.918626+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: CREATE TABLE messenger_messages (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, body LONGTEXT NOT NULL, headers LONGTEXT NOT NULL, queue_name VARCHAR(190) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)', available_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)', delivered_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)', INDEX IDX_75EA56E0FB7336F0 (queue_name), INDEX IDX_75EA56E0E3BD61CE (available_at), INDEX IDX_75EA56E016BA31DB (delivered_at), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB {"sql":"CREATE TABLE messenger_messages (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, body LONGTEXT NOT NULL, headers LONGTEXT NOT NULL, queue_name VARCHAR(190) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)', available_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)', delivered_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)', INDEX IDX_75EA56E0FB7336F0 (queue_name), INDEX IDX_75EA56E0E3BD61CE (available_at), INDEX IDX_75EA56E016BA31DB (delivered_at), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.935164+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: ALTER TABLE director ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1E90D3F0E7D23F1A FOREIGN KEY (person_type_id) REFERENCES person_type (id) {"sql":"ALTER TABLE director ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1E90D3F0E7D23F1A FOREIGN KEY (person_type_id) REFERENCES person_type (id)"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:50.984549+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: ALTER TABLE director ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1E90D3F037A4F92F FOREIGN KEY (gender_type_id) REFERENCES gender_type (id) {"sql":"ALTER TABLE director ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1E90D3F037A4F92F FOREIGN KEY (gender_type_id) REFERENCES gender_type (id)"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:51.072956+01:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: INSERT INTO doctrine_migration_versions (version, executed_at, execution_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?) (parameters: array{"1":"DoctrineMigrations\\Version20240114121747","2":"2024-01-27 09:12:50","3":270}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2,"3":1}) {"sql":"INSERT INTO doctrine_migration_versions (version, executed_at, execution_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)","params":{"1":"DoctrineMigrations\\Version20240114121747","2":"2024-01-27 09:12:50","3":270},"types":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":1}} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:51.103457+01:00] deprecation.INFO: User Deprecated: Context: trying to commit a transaction Problem: the transaction is already committed, relying on silencing is deprecated. Solution: override `AbstractMigration::isTransactional()` so that it returns false. Automate that by setting `transactional` to false in the configuration. More details at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/stable/explanation/implicit-commits.html (TransactionHelper.php:20 called by DbalExecutor.php:191, https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/1169, package doctrine/migrations) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Context: trying to commit a transaction\nProblem: the transaction is already committed, relying on silencing is deprecated.\nSolution: override `AbstractMigration::isTransactional()` so that it returns false.\nAutomate that by setting `transactional` to false in the configuration.\nMore details at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/stable/explanation/implicit-commits.html (TransactionHelper.php:20 called by DbalExecutor.php:191, https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/1169, package doctrine/migrations) at D:\\workspace\\PHP\\SYMFONY\\webapp3\\vendor\\doctrine\\deprecations\\lib\\Doctrine\\Deprecations\\Deprecation.php:210)"} []
[2024-01-27T09:12:53.369089+01:00] doctrine.INFO: Disconnecting [] []
```

Comment: Why are the two different environments using different databse products? Mariadb and mysql are not the same as these two products forked iver 15 years ago! Use the same databse down to the minor version.

Comment: Please provide the SQL statement that it is complaining about.

Comment: @Shadow I don't understand your comment sorry. My problem it's that doctrine migration failed when I launch since my php container, and I don't  why.

Comment: I just added the SQL statement in the post.

Comment: Based on your question, the migration works fine with mariadb, but produces error on mysql 8.2. You really should not use two different database products in your app development between different environments, this setup is asking for trouble! I guess mariadb figures out TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME condition in the subquery, but mysql cannot

Comment: No I don't use two environments for my project. I use docker to launch my environment but I would test with Xampp to know if my migration working. And my migration work but not with Docker.

Comment: It's work when I kill my volume before each launch, but it's not a solution.

Comment: Ok I understood, It' work when I change my mysql container to mariadb:10.5.5.